# Sorting a dictionary based on its child dictionary

Tags: python

I want to sort this dictionary according to age

I have tried some ways to sort this like create a list of the age the sort that but then i won't able to assign the age to its corresonding index

```
students = {
    'a': {
        "age":18,
        "class": "IV"
    },
    'b': {
        "age":19,
        "class": "IV"
    },
    'c': {
        "age":17,
        "class": "IV"
    },
    'd': {
        "age":17.5,
        "class": "IV"
    },
    'e': {
        "age":19.5,
        "class": "IV"
    },
}
```

Comment: you can't guarantee order with regular dicts, use `OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: @eagr only for versions 3.6 and below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: Do any of the answers below solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: v for k, v in sorted(students.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['age'])}
```

Output:

```
{'c': {'age': 17, 'class': 'IV'},
 'd': {'age': 17.5, 'class': 'IV'},
 'a': {'age': 18, 'class': 'IV'},
 'b': {'age': 19, 'class': 'IV'},
 'e': {'age': 19.5, 'class': 'IV'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the builtin `sorted` function.

```py
students_sorted = dict(sorted(students.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["age"]))
```

students_sorted:

```
{
  'c': {'age': 17, 'class': 'IV'}, 
  'd': {'age': 17.5, 'class': 'IV'},
  'a': {'age': 18, 'class': 'IV'}, 
  'b': {'age': 19, 'class': 'IV'}, 
  'e': {'age': 19.5, 'class': 'IV'}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you can to sort the key/value pairs of your dict by a custom sort key function and then put it back together

```
sorted_students = {
    key: value for key, value in sorted(
        students.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['age']
    )
}
```